# Python/Pyinstaller - onefile executable

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, exe

In order to create a python .exe file I have been using pyinstaller and this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w -i favicon.ico "program.py"
```

This creates a /dist folder which contains the generated .exe file.
The problem is that I am not able to run this .exe file without including the following program files inside the .exe launching folder.

```
+ Dir
  - favicon.ico
  - logo.gif
  - data.csv

  - program.exe
```

How can I include the .ico, .gif and .csv INSIDE the .exe so it truly becomes "onefile"?

Comment: Isn't the path to those files enough?

Comment: Yes it is, but if I want to distribute the .exe, it should not be necessary to download the .ico, .gif and .csv as well. These should be included in the .exe some how!?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite new to python so I apologize in advance if the code is a little chaotic. I faced a similar problem with .csv files. I managed to pack them into .py files by once running this code:

```
import csv

myfinalvariable=[]

with open(PathToOriginalCsv + '\\' + 'NameOfCsv.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     myfirstvariable = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
     for line in myfirstvariable:
         myfinalvariable.append(' '.join(line).split())

pyfile=open('PathToDesiredFile\mynewfile.py', 'w')
pyfile.write('newcsv=%s' %(myfinalvariable))
pyfile.close
```

You can iterate this if you have multiple csv files. Now you have the py file with 'variables' and you can 'forget' about the csv files. Because if you put the created py file into your 'project folder' and put:

```
from mynewfile import newcsv, newcsv2, ...
```

into your code, you can modify your code to use the variables 'newcsv', 'newcsv2', etc. instead of loading the original csv files. When you use pyinstaller with the `--onefile` parameter, it packs the 'mynewfile.py' file into the created exe file. Pyinstaller 3.0 also packs the .ico file when using the parameter `--icon=favicon.ico`. Tested on Windows, Python3.4, Pyinstaller3.0. I understand this is an old question, I hope this helps someone who stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 0):

By writing a shell script, that can be executed by powershell,

1. The file can be made and written as a .exe file
2. The other files can be `moved` into the new directory.

Now all that needs done is having the Powershell script to run.

Comment: So there is no way to pack the .py .ico, .gif and .csv inside a single .exe, using only Pyinstaller?

Comment: @sepi Not that I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 0):

You can package the files with pyinstaller's `--add-data` option. For example with your files you should try:

```
> pyinstaller --onefile -w -i favicon.ico "program.py" --add-data "favicon.ico:favicon.ico'\
  --add-data "lgog.gif:logo.gif" --add-data "data.csv:data.csv"
```

On other OS it may be required to replace the `\` with a `^` (or do it all on one line.)

This should package all the files into the exe.

If you want to access these files from the code you need to add a little bit extra, otherwise the program will not find them.

```
import os, sys
def resource(relative_path):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)

    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), relative_path)
```

When pyinstaller compiles a script it sets the `_MEIPASS` variable to the temporary path of the created files at run-time. This script harnesses that to locate these file and defaults back to the ordinary path in un-compiled mode [read more](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html).

To access the files from the code, just replace all links to the files with `resource('myfile.etc')`. For example, using youe `data.csv` file

```
with open(resource('data.csv'), 'r') as csvfile:
    # do stuff
```